# Prove $\frac{2}{3}(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2})+4abc \leq 6abc$, given $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=3$

Tags: inequality

Let, $a, b, c$ be a postive real number with $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=3$. Prove $\frac{2}{3}(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2})+4abc \leq 6abc$

This is what I have so far

since $$(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2})=(a+b+c)^{2}-2(ab+bc+ca)$$

and I have that $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=3 \implies bc+ac+ab=3abc$$

I do not if I can make sense out of that. Any idea how would I do that

Comment: I think the sign is flipped. Try $a = b = 2, c = 1/2$.

Comment: $$\frac{2}{3}(4+4+\frac{1}{4} ) \leq 2(2)(2)\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Your LHS = 5.5 while RHS = 4.

Answer (score 3):

$2(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca) = (a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2\geq 0$

and so

$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq ab + bc + ca = 3abc$